# Java - Two methods with same name, same argument of different type, but the types are related hierarchically

Tags: java, methods, overloading

Let's say I have

```
Interface A {
   public void doSomething(Object a);
}

Interface B {
   public void doSomething(Foo b);
}
```

and

```
Class C implements A, B {

   public void doSomething(Object a) {  print("a"); }
   public void doSomething(Foo b) { print("b"); }

}
```

I guess calling new `C.doSomething(new Foo());` will print `"b"`, even though Foo extends Object.

but what about if I want a common behavior from *sub-methods*:

```
Class C implements A, B {

   public void doSomething(Object a) {  print("common behavior from " + a ); }
   public void doSomething(Foo b) { doSomething((Object) b); }
   public void doSomething(Bar c) { doSomething((Object) c);}

}
```

Will that work when I call `doSomething` with `Foo` and `Bar` or will they end up in an infinite loop because at the end doing `((Object) c) instanceof Bar == true`?

How does Java defines which method to call?

Comment: You should try it and find out. Java defines the behavior in it's [specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overload resolution happens at compile time. It doesn't matter what the runtime type of `b` or `c` is. As long as they're cast as `Object`, it'll call the `Object` overload. So your example should work fine.

Another common use case is where you want to pass a literal `null` to a method and you need to cast it to some type to avoid overload ambiguity. E.g. `c.doSomething((Foo)null)`.

Comment: Using the null parameter is a good example explanation. Thank you.